# htaccess - deny from all not working for files uploaded with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am hoping you can help, I have been having real trouble getting a .htaccess file for work correctly.

I am trying to block of all access to files and folders within the wp-content/uploads/ folder

i have resorted to placing a .htaccess file in each subdirectory with:

deny from all

This works OK if i FTP a file up and try to access it, the trouble is if i use wordpress to upload a file (in to the same folder) this file is accessible

any ideas on whats going on and a solution?

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try to write some rule in .htaccess file something like.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will allow you to block off all access to files and folders within the wp-content/uploads/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Once I updated wildcard to include .html (root htaccess), my deny all in the subdirectory worked just fine.

From this:

```
<Files *> 
order deny,allow 
deny from env=notallowed 
allow from env=allowsome 
</Files>
```

To this:
     
    order deny,allow 
    deny from env=notallowed 
    allow from env=allowsome